# how to phrase a single line json file in snowflake external table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

this is the first time I try to load a single line json file into snowflake via external table.
the files are around 60MB and stored on s3. it contains nest records, arrays and **no** newline character.

Right now I cannot see the data from the external table, However, if the file is small enough like 1MB the external table works fine.
The closest solution I can find is [this](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009GwPvv/i-cannot-get-external-table-to-work-even-though-i-read-the-document-at-least-10-times), but it doesn't provide me sufficient answer.
The file can be in a much bigger size and I have no control of the files.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

thanks!

Edit:
Look like the only tangible solution is to make the file smaller, as the json file is not ndjson. [What JSON format does STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491416/what-json-format-does-strip-outer-array-support)

Comment: Please share more code and error messages, so we can reproduce your problem. Sample files? External table setup?

Answer (score 0):

If your nested records are wrapped in an outer array, you can potentially use STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY on the Stage file definition to remove them so each JSON element within the outer array gets loaded as a record. You can include use METADATA$FILENAME in the table definition to derive which file the elements came from.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, thanks for your answer

Comment: STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY doesn't really work for my case, see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491416/what-json-format-does-strip-outer-array-support